# Overful hbox with chemformula

Tags: line-breaking, boxes, chemformula

Chemical formulae often give overful hboxes.

How do I prevent that, and I mean something more automatic than just adding a `\linebreak` everywhere where this is an issue?

Should not Latex put a box (and every letter or word or syllable is a box, isn't it?) on the next line if it does not fit on the current one? This is especially true, when i explicitly put the formula in a `mbox` which gives the same result in the example.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage[british,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{modules={scheme}}
\renewcommand\cmpd[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\begin{document}
\section{Ziel des Versuchs}
Ziel des Versuchs war die Synthese des Katalysators \iupac{Tetra|kis(tri|phenyl|phos|phin)palladium(0)} (\ch{[Pd(PPh3)4]}, \cmpd{3}) und dessen Verwendung in einer Kreuzkupplungsreaktion zur Synthese von Biphenyl (\cmpd{6}).
\end{document}
```

[image]

writing

```
\mbox{\ch{[Pd(PPh3)4]}}
```

does not change anything

Comment: Sometimes you just have to help manually. If you add `showframe` to the geometry options in your MWE you see that only the minor part of the formula sticks into the margin. Instead of `\linebreak` you can put the complete paragraph in `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` (in addition you then need to put the `(0)` part in between `$...$` due to a bug in `chemmacros` which will be fixed in v5.8a).